# Portal 2 Authoring Tools

Tags: portal-2

[IGN](http://pc.ign.com/articles/116/1167445p1.html) mentioned recently there was no information, just wanted to see if anyone else knew differently. Has there been any announcement of Portal 2 level authoring tools for PS3?  I see there is beta software for the PC.

Will Portal 2 authored levels be playable on all platforms, or just PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools will be only available for PC, the maps will be playable on all platforms according to this source: http://www.nowgamer.com/news/5030/portal-2-mod-levels-for-all-platforms

Answer (score 1):

You can currently use the Alien Swarm SDK to map, from what I have heard.